# How know difference between execution by action menu and debug?

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have google spreadsheet with some custom menu.

How my script can know when is invoke it because the user clic on custom menu and when it execute by user use script editor for debugging ?

How can i know difference between both instances ?

i was try with something like :

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi() === undefined
```

but i want try something else

The main goal, is let user with editor rights can use custom menus but when they want debug with the Script Editor the code of my Lybrary, block this action.

I'am working over a Library, and i want avoid that users can read the code of Library. I know that Addon can help in this way. But i want work with Libraries

---

FINAL ANSWER

There is not way to find a diffetence.
For the main goal, we need coding ADDONS 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/

Comment: A menu item can not pass a parameter to a function, but a regular function can pass a parameter to another function, so you could pass some value to the function, and if that value exists then it's from another function and not from the menu.

Comment: Actually, your script can't tell the difference.  You could put an intermediate function between the menu and the real function. But someone in the script editor could read that and say oh I'll run the intermediate function as if I were running the function from the menu and @puentesdiaz will never know the difference and you couldn't tell the difference.  Anyway what's the point of your question?  What do you wish to accomplish with this knowledge?

Comment: The main idea is avoid for users can debug code but can use menus